# Project structure for Go program to run on AWS Lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I found the following code sample from the [AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-go-support-for-aws-lambda/):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Body:       "Hello World",
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

Since lambda.Start only takes in one handler and the entry point for a Go program is the main function, does that mean one CodeStar project can only consist of one handler?

I understand that lambda functions should be small in size and preferably handle one functionality, but it seems that one would need to create a lot of projects and that would be hard to manage. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: This is very helpful and can be seen many internal Go tools (by Google I mean). And it has some semantics that tools understand, like if a package from another project tries to import from `internal`s of current project, compiler will fail. https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I have come up with so far

Project folder structure:

```
project
  folder1
    main.go
  folder2
    main.go
  buildspec.yml
  template.yml
```

buildspec.yml:

```
...

build:
    commands:
      - cd folder1
      - go build -o main
      - cd ../folder2
      - go build -o main
....
```

template.yml:

```
....

Resources:
  GetTest1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./folder1
      Handler: main
      Runtime: go1.x
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test1
            Method: get
  GetTest2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./folder2
      Handler: main
      Runtime: go1.x
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test2
            Method: get   
....
```

It is important to note that all main.go files in the subdirectories namely, `folder1/main.go`, `folder2/main.go`, need to be in `package main`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Seems to me that you are creating 2 separate lambdas here. Nothing wrong with that (it's actually not abusing the model), I just assumed you were interested with only 1 lambda resource based on OP.

Comment: @Nebril I probably didn't make myself clear in my question. I appreciate your input though

Comment: Where do external dependencies get imported from? E.g. other peoples code

Answer (score 5):

Your `handler` func is your entry point, but since you can call it with arbitrary json data, you can have multiple functions called from within your `handler` based on the data you send to handler.

`APIGatewayProxyRequest` has `Body` field. What you do based on that is up to you.

The idea of lambda (AFAIU) is to have minimal binaries that do only one thing though. Implementing complex applications with request routing from within lambda seems like abusing the model to me, but it's doable.